# mrjob not finding input file

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using the cloudera Virtual Machine. Here's my file structure:

```
[cloudera@quickstart pydoop]$ hdfs dfs -ls -R /input
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2015-10-02 15:00 /input/test1
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup         62 2015-10-02 15:00 /input/test1/file1.txt
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera supergroup          0 2015-10-02 14:59 /input/test2
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup    1428841 2015-10-02 14:59 /input/test2/5000-8.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup     674570 2015-10-02 14:59 /input/test2/pg20417.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup    1573151 2015-10-02 14:59 /input/test2/pg4300.txt
```

Here's my code to execute the wordcount example:

```
python /home/cloudera/MapReduceCode/mrjob/wordcount1.py -r hadoop hdfs://input/test1/file1.txt
```

It crashes with the following. It seems like it can't find the file.

```
[cloudera@quickstart hadoop]$ python /home/cloudera/MapReduceCode/mrjob/wordcount1.py -r hadoop hdfs://input/test1/file1.txt
no configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
no configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cloudera/MapReduceCode/mrjob/wordcount1.py", line 13, in <module>
    MRWordCount.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 461, in run
    mr_job.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 479, in execute
    super(MRJob, self).execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 153, in execute
    self.run_job()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 216, in run_job
    runner.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/runner.py", line 470, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/hadoop.py", line 233, in _run
    self._check_input_exists()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/hadoop.py", line 247, in _check_input_exists
    if not self.path_exists(path):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/fs/composite.py", line 78, in path_exists
    return self._do_action('path_exists', path_glob)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/fs/composite.py", line 54, in _do_action
    return getattr(fs, action)(path, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/fs/hadoop.py", line 212, in path_exists
    ok_stderr=[_HADOOP_LS_NO_SUCH_FILE])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/fs/hadoop.py", line 86, in invoke_hadoop
    proc = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does it work if you leave out the hdfs:// from the start of you input path?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work :-(

Comment: `hdfs://input...` is wrong. You need **three** slashes otherwise the code tries to access a remote machine called `input`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow steps as below on **`Cloudera Quickstart VM`** to get it working.

1. Ensure **`HADOOP_HOME`** is set.

   **`export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop`**
2. Create **`symlink`** to **`hadoop-streaming.jar`

   **`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar /usr/lib/hadoop`**
3. use **`hdfs:///`** instead of **`hdfs://`**

   **`python /home/cloudera/MapReduceCode/mrjob/wordcount1.py -r hadoop hdfs:///input/test1/file1.txt`**

below is the complete **`mrjob`** result from **`my cloudera quickstart VM`**.

Note: location of wordcount1.py & file1.txt is different than yours but it doesn't matter.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ python wordcount1.py -r hadoop hdfs:///user/cloudera/file1.txt
no configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
no configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
creating tmp directory /tmp/wordcount1.cloudera.20151011.115958.773999
writing wrapper script to /tmp/wordcount1.cloudera.20151011.115958.773999/setup-wrapper.sh
Using Hadoop version 2.6.0
Copying local files into hdfs:///user/cloudera/tmp/mrjob/wordcount1.cloudera.20151011.115958.773999/files/

PLEASE NOTE: Starting in mrjob v0.5.0, protocols will be strict by default. It's recommended you run your job with --strict-protocols or set up mrjob.conf as described at https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/whats-new.html#ready-for-strict-protocols

HADOOP: packageJobJar: [] [/usr/jars/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.4.2.jar] /tmp/streamjob3860196653022444549.jar tmpDir=null
HADOOP: Connecting to ResourceManager at quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032
HADOOP: Connecting to ResourceManager at quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032
HADOOP: Total input paths to process : 1
HADOOP: number of splits:2
HADOOP: Submitting tokens for job: job_1444564543695_0003
HADOOP: Submitted application application_1444564543695_0003
HADOOP: The url to track the job: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1444564543695_0003/
HADOOP: Running job: job_1444564543695_0003
HADOOP: Job job_1444564543695_0003 running in uber mode : false
HADOOP:  map 0% reduce 0%
HADOOP:  map 100% reduce 0%
HADOOP:  map 100% reduce 100%
HADOOP: Job job_1444564543695_0003 completed successfully
HADOOP: Counters: 49
HADOOP:     File System Counters
HADOOP:         FILE: Number of bytes read=105
HADOOP:         FILE: Number of bytes written=356914
HADOOP:         FILE: Number of read operations=0
HADOOP:         FILE: Number of large read operations=0
HADOOP:         FILE: Number of write operations=0
HADOOP:         HDFS: Number of bytes read=322
HADOOP:         HDFS: Number of bytes written=32
HADOOP:         HDFS: Number of read operations=9
HADOOP:         HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
HADOOP:         HDFS: Number of write operations=2
HADOOP:     Job Counters 
HADOOP:         Launched map tasks=2
HADOOP:         Launched reduce tasks=1
HADOOP:         Data-local map tasks=2
HADOOP:         Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=1164160
HADOOP:         Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=350080
HADOOP:         Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=9095
HADOOP:         Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=2735
HADOOP:         Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=9095
HADOOP:         Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=2735
HADOOP:         Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=1164160
HADOOP:         Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=350080
HADOOP:     Map-Reduce Framework
HADOOP:         Map input records=5
HADOOP:         Map output records=15
HADOOP:         Map output bytes=153
HADOOP:         Map output materialized bytes=152
HADOOP:         Input split bytes=214
HADOOP:         Combine input records=0
HADOOP:         Combine output records=0
HADOOP:         Reduce input groups=3
HADOOP:         Reduce shuffle bytes=152
HADOOP:         Reduce input records=15
HADOOP:         Reduce output records=3
HADOOP:         Spilled Records=30
HADOOP:         Shuffled Maps =2
HADOOP:         Failed Shuffles=0
HADOOP:         Merged Map outputs=2
HADOOP:         GC time elapsed (ms)=148
HADOOP:         CPU time spent (ms)=1470
HADOOP:         Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=428871680
HADOOP:         Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=2197188608
HADOOP:         Total committed heap usage (bytes)=144179200
HADOOP:     Shuffle Errors
HADOOP:         BAD_ID=0
HADOOP:         CONNECTION=0
HADOOP:         IO_ERROR=0
HADOOP:         WRONG_LENGTH=0
HADOOP:         WRONG_MAP=0
HADOOP:         WRONG_REDUCE=0
HADOOP:     File Input Format Counters 
HADOOP:         Bytes Read=108
HADOOP:     File Output Format Counters 
HADOOP:         Bytes Written=32
HADOOP: Output directory: hdfs:///user/cloudera/tmp/mrjob/wordcount1.cloudera.20151011.115958.773999/output
Counters from step 1:
  (no counters found)
Streaming final output from hdfs:///user/cloudera/tmp/mrjob/wordcount1.cloudera.20151011.115958.773999/output
"chars" 67
"lines" 5
"words" 16
removing tmp directory /tmp/wordcount1.cloudera.20151011.115958.773999
deleting hdfs:///user/cloudera/tmp/mrjob/wordcount1.cloudera.20151011.115958.773999 from HDFS
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$
```

Comment: Awesome that worked! Thanks. Can you explain the purpose of step 2? Also, there are two mapreduce directories, "hadoop" and "hadoop-0.20-mapreduce" in /usr/lib/. What's the difference?